# Mikro-Orm migrations probelm with mysql

Tags: mysql, npx, mikro-orm

In doing a react application, I'm trying to use a migration from CLI using the `npx mikro-orm migration:create` command.

I have my export default's type set as "mysql", my database is created, but when I run the command, it returns the following error :

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

I was just trying to follow a tutorial, except the tutorial used postgresql, so I don't really know where to start looking to fix the problem. I suppose it's got something to do with the ports and addresses and things of the two services not being synchronized but that's just a wild guess... Could someone point me towards an actual solution ?

Comment: Your database is either not running or is at different address/port.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through the same problem and after a lot of research I just gave up and decided to change my db for sqlite3.

```
sudo apt-get sqlite3
```

Then you just need to install

```
 npm i @mikro-orm/sqlite
```

Then type

```
 sqlite3
```

It will open the `sqlite3>  your_database.db`

CHANGE dbName and type inside `mikro-orm.config.ts` file and it should work fine without password.

and then run your migration normally: `npx mikro-orm migration:create`

these problems are wasting of time and we should go ahead and enjoy the tutorial.